# method='predict_proba' for cross_val_predict return "index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is the part of the data set:

```
a b c result
0 1 1  positive
0 0 1  negative
0 1 1  negative
0 0 0  positive


result = [1 if v=='positive' else 0 for v in data['result'].tolist()]

Output = result
X = data["a", "b", "c"]
y = np.reshape(Output, (X.shape[0], 1))
```

I am trying to use the cross-validation method in sklearn  to predict the class of X data: This part of my codes work:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression('l2')
y_pred_class = cross_val_predict(logreg, X, y, cv=10, method= 'predict' )
```

but when I want to calculate probabily of a class using this code:

```
y_pred_prob = cross_val_predict(logreg, X, y, cv=10, method='predict_proba')
```

It has this error:

```
index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `method="predict"` you are getting a warning:

> DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
> return f(**kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:72: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
> return f(**kwargs)

If you simply heed that warning, it will solve the error in `method="predict_proba"`. And all you need to do is change this line

```
y = np.reshape(Output, (X.shape[0], 1))
```

to

```
y = np.reshape(Output, (X.shape[0],))
```

or even

```
y = np.array(result)
```

or don't even bother with the list comprehension and stay in pandas:

```
y = data["result"].replace({"positive": 1, "negative": 0})
```